# cannot update devDependencies in new file

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, less

First post here, hi all.

I'm learning Less from *Learning Less.js* (Packt) and following it's steps in setting up the  environment (chapter 2).

First time using node.js, I installed in the default directory. Thereafter I created my first grunt project and saved it, then navigated cmd to its parent folder and executed `npm install -g --save-dev`.

Problem:
The book asserts that devDependencies should update, but it does not.

My first grunt project code:

```
{
  "name": "my_grunt_project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

Attempting some solutions posted here, I tried executing `npm update --save-dev`, but received warnings and devDependencies didn't update. The warnings were *No description*, *No repository field* and, *No license field*.

What will it take to get it to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install -g --save-dev` specifies no package to download and save within the dev dependencies object of `package.json` (the `-g` flag is for global npm installs - usually CLI utilities and not managed under `package.json`).  To download a package and save it as a dev dependency, run `npm install package-name --save-dev`.

Comment: I'm too new to know anything about this, yet determined to learn, and right now I'm only "getting my feet wet". The book  shows devDependencies populated with three attributes: _grunt_, _grunt-contrib-less_ and, _grunt-contrib-watch_. What must I type in the command window to get my file to update so?

Comment: `npm install "package name" --save-dev` replace "package name" with the packages you listed in your comment.  Example: `npm install grunt-contrib-less --save-dev`

Comment: Still getting errors:  
  
C:\Projects\LessJs>npm install grunt-contrib-less --save-dev  \n  
my_grunt_project@0.0.1 C:\Projects\LessJs  \n  
`-- grunt-contrib-less@1.3.0  \n  
  | `-- source-map@0.5.6  \n  
  \n  
...(tree)
  \n  
  `-- lodash@4.12.0  \n  
  \n  
npm WARN my_grunt_project@0.0.1 No description  \n  
npm WARN my_grunt_project@0.0.1 No repository field.  \n  
npm WARN my_grunt_project@0.0.1 No license field.  \n

Comment: Just checked, and noticed that despite the errors the devDependencies were updated.  Any idea why I get these errors, and how to configure the system so that they are no longer there?

Comment: You're getting warnings, not errors, and as far as why, you can break apart the log and google the individual errors for additional insights